# microsoft notification webhook

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

I have application who is getting notifications from Outlook, it is subscribed for update,create changes in users mailboxes. I am getting notifications all day long even if the users are not active (It is their sleep time). Can I know how notifications are sent to me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of background tasks (assistants), both time based and event based that wake up and do work on the system.  In addition, there may be apps that the user has given permissions to operate on their mailbox that may be doing something behind the scenes.  Exchange doesn't differentiate.  When a change is made that matches the criteria in the subscription, a notification will be generated.